# Problems with npy to nii.gz conversion

Tags: python, numpy, nibabel

I'm trying to convert a `.npy` image to a `nii.gz` image, I'm having various problems even though I'm following instructions correctly.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib

file_dir = "D:/teste volumes slicer/"
fileNPY1 = "teste01.npy"
img_array1 = np.load(file_dir + fileNPY1)
print(img_array1.shape)
print(img_array1.dtype)

normal_array = "D:/teste volumes slicer/teste01.npy"
print ("done")
nifti_file = nib.Nifti1Image(normal_array, np.eye(4))
```

About the image: (332, 360, 360) float64 (this is what we got when we print the shape and dtype)
[https://ibb.co/mRyTrw7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBazU.png) - image that shows the error and the image's information

```
The error message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\teste volumes slicer\conversor.py", line 16, in <module>
    nifti_file = nib.Nifti1Image(normal_array, np.eye(4))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\nifti1.py", line 1756, in __init__
    super(Nifti1Pair, self).__init__(dataobj,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\analyze.py", line 918, in __init__
    super(AnalyzeImage, self).__init__(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\spatialimages.py", line 469, in __init__
    self.update_header()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\nifti1.py", line 2032, in update_header
    super(Nifti1Image, self).update_header()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\nifti1.py", line 1795, in update_header
    super(Nifti1Pair, self).update_header()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\spatialimages.py", line 491, in update_header
    shape = self._dataobj.shape
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: ```normal_array``` is just a string :/ you should load the data (npy file), Although you had loaded the data and it is ```img_array1```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is instead of passing your Numpy-array (your image), you are passing the path of the image to the `Nifti1Image` function.

This is the correct way to convert it:

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib

file_dir = "D:/teste volumes slicer/"
fileNPY1 = "teste01.npy"
img_array1 = np.load(file_dir + fileNPY1) 
nifti_file = nib.Nifti1Image(img_array1 , np.eye(4))
```

Comment: Hey, can you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685859/how-can-i-save-an-image-nii-gz-after-reshaping-it