# How can I save an image (nii.gz) after reshaping it?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I'm trying to reshape an image after reshaping it, I'm facing problems when it comes to the saving method. Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
from nibabel.testing import data_path
import os
example_filename = os.path.join("D:/Volumes convertidos LIDC", 
'teste001converted.nii.gz')
img = nib.load('teste001converted.nii.gz')
print (img.shape)
newimg = img.get_fdata().reshape(332,360*360)
print (newimg.shape)
final_img = nib.Nifti1Image(newimg, img.affine)
nib.save(final_img, os.path.join("D:/Volumes convertidos LIDC", 
'test2d.nii.gz'))
```

And I'm getting an error:

(most recent call last):

File "d:\Volumes convertidos LIDC\reshape.py", line 17, in 
final_img = nib.Nifti1Image(newimg, img.affine)

File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\nifti1.py", line 1756, in **init**
super(Nifti1Pair, self).**init**(dataobj,

File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\analyze.py", line 918, in **init**
super(AnalyzeImage, self).**init**(
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\spatialimages.py", line 469, in **init**
self.update_header()

File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\nifti1.py", line 2032, in update_header
super(Nifti1Image, self).update_header()
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\nifti1.py", line 1795, in update_header
super(Nifti1Pair, self).update_header()

File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\spatialimages.py", line 496, in update_header
hdr.set_data_shape(shape)

File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\nifti1.py", line 880, in set_data_shape
super(Nifti1Header, self).set_data_shape(shape)

File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nibabel\analyze.py", line 633, in set_data_shape

```
raise HeaderDataError(f'shape {shape} does not fit in dim datatype')
```

nibabel.spatialimages.HeaderDataError: shape (332, 129600) does not fit in dim datatype

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I don't think this question should flagged as a duplicate. As for as I am concerned, this particular error message has not been mentioned in any other question at SO.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: I just changed, thank you @gre_gor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to save a `numpy` array, whereas the `nib.save` expects a `SpatialImage` object.

You should convert the `numpy` array to a `SpatialImage`:

```
final_img = nib.Nifti1Image(newimg, img.affine)
```

After which you can save the image:

```
nib.save(final_img, os.path.join("D:/Volumes convertidos LIDC", 'test4d.nii.gz'))
```

See the [documentation](https://nipy.org/nibabel/reference/nibabel.loadsave.html#nibabel.loadsave.save) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56635988/11919175) for more explanation.

**Edit:** This will not work if `newimg` is a 2D image.

Comment: Thank you for you input, unfortunately your solution is not working, I'm getting this error: HeaderDataError: shape (332, 129600) does not fit in dim datatype

Comment: @MauricésarBarbosa please edit your question and add the complete code and errors, so I can check it.

Comment: I just did @A.Najafi

Comment: You have loaded a 3D image and reshaped it into a 2D image. That might be the problem. Apparently,  either `NiftiImage` does not accept 2D images, `img.affine` has some 3D information that does not match with `newimg`.

Comment: The following NiBabel tutorial explicitly states this: "The image data array: a 3D or 4D array of image data." https://nipy.org/nibabel/coordinate_systems.html